# Have any old Pokemon been made exclusively Fairy type?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In Pokemon X&Y, Nintendo have introduced the Fairy type, and have gone back and retro-fitted a bunch of old Pokemon with this new type as it's secondary type.

But is there any Pokemon from previous generations that has had it's type changed to be **exclusively** Fairy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleffa, Clefairy, Clefable, Togepi, Snubbull, and Granbull have been changed to pure Fairy-type.

Comment: Snubbull and Granbull too? No wonder they didn't go down with Fighter type moves...

Comment: @Nolonar - Snubbull & Granbull were always listed as a 'fairy pokemon' in the Pokedex, which I always thought was wierd